# Cannot position div to bottom 0px with CSS

Tags: html, css

I' am trying to position a div on my site to bottom 0px. Please see the code below. This div with position 0px is wrap inside another div.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="top-wrap">
    <div class="clearfix top-cleafix">
        <div class="test">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.clearfix{
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

.top-wrap{
    height: 341px;
    background: #F00;
    width: 100%;    
}

.top-cleafix{
    height: 100%;
}

.test{
    bottom: 0px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.test{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px; 
    width:100%;   
}
.top-wrap{
    height: 341px;
    background: #F00;
    width: 100%;    
    position:relative; //add relative position
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ETCnZ/1)

Comment: hi Hiral, This CSS positions the div to bottom 0px of the page. I want to position it to the bottom 0px of .test

Answer (score 1):

add

```
   position:absolute;
```

or

```
   position:relative;
```

based on content

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.test{
    float: bottom; 
vertical-align:bottom;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add absolute position in test and relative in top-wrap

```
.top-wrap{
    position:relative;
    height: 341px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 100%;    
}

.clearfix{
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

.top-cleafix{
    height: 100%;
}

.test{
    bottom: 0px;  
    position: absolute;
```

}

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NpbCc/)